# SELECT only for existed YEARS to be displayed in ComboBox

Tags: c#, sql, wpf

I'm using `Microsoft SqlServer`

I want to fill my combobox only with YEARS that existed in a Table.

**Example:**

```
    Date     |
             |
 06/22/2016  |
 06/22/2016  |
 07/21/2016  |
 02/22/2017  |
 05/10/2017  |
```

The data that I want to display in my combobox is:

`2016`
`2017`

My code didn't work, it doesn't display anything.

Here's my current code:

```
        string thisQuery = "SELECT DISTINCT DATEPART(YYYY, [Date]) FROM [TransportRecord]";
        using (SqlConnection thisSqlConnection = new SqlConnection(theConnectionString))
        using (SqlCommand thisSqlCommand = new SqlCommand(thisQuery, thisSqlConnection)) {
            using (SqlDataAdapter thisSqlDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(thisSqlCommand))
            using (DataTable thisDataTable = new DataTable()) {
                thisSqlDataAdapter.Fill(thisDataTable);
                ComboBox_SearchYear.ItemsSource = thisDataTable.DefaultView;
                ComboBox_SearchYear.DisplayMemberPath = "Date";
                ComboBox_SearchYear.SelectedValuePath = "Date";
                ComboBox_SearchYear.SelectedValue = DateTime.Now;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change:

```
string thisQuery = "SELECT DISTINCT DATEPART(YYYY, [Date]) FROM [TransportRecord]";
```

to:

```
string thisQuery = "SELECT DISTINCT DATEPART(YYYY, [Date]) as [Date] FROM [TransportRecord]";
```